# Insert and update Statement with in Text Changed event

Tags: c#, windows

I have a requirement where I have to take form total value when ever total changes, and insert or update in to table. I am using Text Changed to calculate the total, and with in the same text changed event I have the insert and update the statements, it is working fine, but, it is slowing down the form load time, in other sense, form is taking much longer time to load and some times form is getting stuck, unable navigate back and forth. I am just wondering if there any other event which I could use to avoid this form load issue.

```
private void txtSchBTotalLiability_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     UpdateBalance();
     bl.UpdateFormOQSWTTaxData(_selectedcompanyid, yearstr, Convert.ToInt32(_qtrstr), !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSchBTotalLiability.Text) ? Convert.ToDecimal(txtSchBTotalLiability.Text) : 0.0m);
     txtSWTax.Text = txtSchBTotalLiability.Text;     
}
```

Comment: Have you tried binding the TextChanged event in the Form Load event instead of from the designer?

Comment: why dont you use a OnLostFocus(EventArgs) event, is it necessary to do it on text changed?

Comment: Don't attach the TextChanged event until after the form is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Make it an asynchronous task. That should unlock the main thread. Also if i'm getting this right is the update/insert happening during the load of the page. Does the form always loads with empty values? If so you should probably skip that the insert/update during the load since the form is empty.

Comment: Hi Salvador, Ignore my previous statement. I have a tree view, and I am only binding the tree view in form load event, rest of the events are in main form class.  when Form loads, it displays  with what ever values that are there in particular table, and user can do edit or add. private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindTree();

        }

Comment: Like LarsTech advices you should attach the event at the end of the load event of the form, after you bind the data. One of the problems is that the data bind in the load is triggering the textchanged event and happening for as many fields you have in the TreeView. Since all this is happening of the main thread the UI freezes while all those updates and inserts happen in the Load. That said i would highly recommend also that you put that insert/update method in a asynchronous task with a progress dialog so that the user knows that the info is being updated.